# Facebook graph api /user does not return gender, other public profile bits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to get the gender of users who like a particular (public) post. I can get a list of app-specific-user-ids of everyone who liked the post, but when I query for their profiles, I only get first and last name:

```
/v2.0/10203862301234567

{u'first_name': u'John',
 u'id': u'10203862301234567',
 u'last_name': u'Doe',
 u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10203862301234567/',
 u'name': u'John Doe'}
```

Even if I specify the fields, I still do not get gender back:

```
/v2.0/10203862301234567?fields=gender

{u'id': u'10203862301234567'}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

It's not from lack of a gender, as I can navigate (logged in to my personal account) to the public post and click through to see their full public profile, which includes age/gender/location/etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same problem.

I can not get the gender directly.

And also I can not get the username and URL of the profile.

This API 2.0 appears to be incomplete. Basic things were lost.

But I managed to get the gender indirectly, through the use of array. See below.

```
// graph api request for user data
 $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo 'sex:'.$graphObject['gender'];
```

Try this. Work for me.

Comment: So, no way to get gender in this case? You have to make another request for each user to get their gender?